# Do dipolar gravitational waves exist?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion, gravitational-waves, multipole-expansion

There seems to be some controversy (see [A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609104), [B](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261037)) on this topic, so I'm posting a new question for discussion and clarification.

By definition, one cannot accelerate the center of mass of a closed system (to do so would require a force from outside the system). So, seen from afar, gravitational waves radiating from a closed system can come only from an accelerating redistribution of mass within the system (quadrupolar effect).  (BTW radiating waves are defined as having a 1/r dependence on distance, rather than 1/r<sup>2</sup> for local static gravitational fields).

[image]

At intermediate distances (large compared to some component of the system but small compared to the whole system), the situation is less clear. For example, in a binary orbiting system with two compact masses, you could be at a large distance from one mass compared with its diameter but at a small distance compared to the separation of the two masses.  So, the question arises: is there a regime where gravitational effects decay closely as 1/r with distance from an individual mass?  An individual mass does not represent a closed system and is not bound by quadrupole effect, so this radiation could be viewed as radiating from a dipolar source.  
Several authors explore the idea that quadrupole radiation can be derived as the residue left from partial cancellation of radiating dipole fields [[C](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0351), [D](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04635)]. The dipole fields from different sources within the closed system do not cancel completely because the sources are not exactly colocated.  Some of these analyses invoke the [gravitoelectromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) approximation as an analogy with electromagnetics.

To some extent this is semantics about what constitutes a radiating field - or perhaps separating the sources is just a mathematical contrivance.  But it seems like an answer could be gauged by looking at numerical simulations to see if there is indeed a $1/r$ regime not too far from one or the other of the two masses but still nearby or inside the total system.

I would value any comments and advice.

Answer (score 1):

> There seems to be some controversy (see A, B) on this topic, so I'm posting a new question for discussion and clarification.

I don't see any controversy indicated in the two links. No, there are no gravitational waves that are dipoles, and this is not controversial.

The multipolarity of a wave is not something that can be sensed locally. It's a description of the wave pattern as a whole. Mathematically, it's an eigenvalue problem. As a physical example, if I observe air pressure at one point as a function of time, I get no information about whether the sound wave was monopole or dipole radiation. Multipolarity is not a property that can be assigned to the near field.

Comment: good comment.  Agreed, there is no controversy about the fact that the far-field radiating from a closed system depends only from fluctuations in the mass distribution (so-called quadrupole effect).  The question asks about the 'far-field' from an object that is part of a closed system but for which momentum is not conserved. Admittedly, the words 'far field' needs some definition.

Comment: user286839 By symmetry, the field pattern in rotating co-ordinates is fixed in space. It can be decomposed into a far-field radiating from a point quadrupole source in the center and a pair of point sources providing the static field from each mass.  Subtracting those fields would give a weird picture, but maybe something in the behavior of the field around each mass could be identified as a dipole contribution?